# How to quantify "rare"

Tags: statistics, definition

When you consider the word **unusual**, it can be mathematically defined as being two standard deviations outside of the mean.  Does the word **rare** have a definition or commonly agreed upon quantifiable method that can describe the word?

Comment: No, rare has no precise mathematical definition, as far as I know. Everyone has some association, though. For me, a *rare point* could be a [non-generic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point). I think you have to specify the question, perhaps making precise the meaning in statistics you have in mind.

Comment: For purposes of hypothesis testing one often uses the 5% significance level. The idea is that an outcome that has less than $0.05$ if the null hypothesis is true, then one rejects the null hypothesis. In various situations levels 10%, 1% and 0.1% are often used, depending on what serious consequences might follow from making a wrong decision. So as @DietrichBurde says, there is no generally accepted value for all situations.

Comment: So, if someone wants to add an answer that says "No", I'll be glad to accept